# Trigger Tab Click and Filter Results Using Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, shuffle

I am using Joomla along with [this template](http://demo2.joomshaper.com/2019/indigo/index.php/portfolio). I would like to create a link on my home page that when clicked, will take the user to the portfolio page and display a pre-selected tab, with filtered results.

For example, my home page link would be 'Branding Portfolio', when clicked, this should go to http://demo2.joomshaper.com/2019/indigo/index.php/portfolio and the 'Branding' tab should be pre-selected, and the items already filtered to display Branding only.

The tab html looks like this;

```
<li data-group="branding"><a href="#">Branding</a></li>
```

I have tried to trigger a click action when the page loads, based on the URL `example.com/portfolio#branding` using this code;

```
<script>
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('.sp-simpleportfolio-filter li[data-group="' + hash + '"] a').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

However the only thing that happens is the tab is highlighted, like it is active. But the results aren't filtered.

Once on the pre-filtered page, I need to be able to switch between the tabs and continue to filter as normal.

I'm not too worried about the animations.

The site appears to be using [shuffle.js](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the following Joomla file (create an override if possible);

> components\com_spsimpleportfolio\assets\js\spsimpleportfolio.js

Add three lines of code;

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var $container = $('.sp-simpleportfolio-items');

    $(window).load(function() {
        var $sizer = $container.find('.shuffle__sizer');

        $container.shuffle({
            itemSelector: '.sp-simpleportfolio-item',
            sequentialFadeDelay: 150,
            sizer: $sizer
        });

        // ADD - get the url hash
        var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
        // ADD - shuffle based on the hash
        $container.shuffle( 'shuffle', hash );
        // ADD - highlight the tab
        $('.sp-simpleportfolio-filter li[data-group="' + hash + '"] a').trigger('click');

    });

});
```

On page load the tabs should be selected and items filtered based on the url hash.